# PHP variable value in jQuery - AJAX load() path location not working

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am using PHP to get info from MYSQL and then passing the row value as variable to a details page using `$_GET` (eg: `$Server= $_GET["Server"];`)

In the details page, I am loading local HTML file using jQuery AJAX load() as below

```
"$("#box").load("<?php echo $Server;?>");"
```

The file is loading perfectly when I copy it to the root folder (website root folder), but if I want to fetch from a different directory its not working.

I want to use something like below

```
"$("#box").load("/Archive/<?php echo $Server;?>");"
```

Thanks,

Comment: What is content of `$Server`?

Comment: You have a public accessible url `mysite.com/Archive/somepage`?

Comment: Its the name of the server (eg: node1), and I have some archive files with server name which I fetch

Comment: We have a script, which keeps generating some files from local servers and dumps in the folder. I am using .load() to fetch the file and show it in the browser when the server name is selected. This process is working as long as i copy the file to root folder, because of the number of files I want to copy them to a different folder and call. The name of the file would be same as $Server which i get from PHP.

Comment: These are local files like D:/archive/node

Comment: check network response on your prefered web developer console! ( dir rights issue ? )

Comment: Javascript is client side. So, you need this url to be public accessible via web browser by the user to make it works. Or the file, or some page that send the file to the user.

Comment: The file will have some application information and properly formatted. When the user clicks on the server name, it takes to the details page and this is where the file will load into the body of the page and visible to users. And all the users are internal

Comment: I am sure I am doing something wrong in the way I am using PHP variable in the HTML load() path, maybe the syntax error which I couldn't figure out. If I don't use the variable and test using the name it works, like "$("#box").load("/Archive/Node1?>");" . Also if i copy the file to root and use "$("#box").load("<?php echo $Server;?>");" it works. The only issue is when I point to a different folder and want to use the variable like "$("#box").load("/Archive/<?php echo $Server;?>");", it fails